# MYSQL closing and reestablishing connection to execute many queries

Tags: python, mysql, database

when i tried executing 30+ queries using a single connection in python script the queries were executed but the changes were not reflected in the database but when i closed and reestablished the connection for every 10 queries and executed the queries seemed to work why did this happen  but this problem hasn't occured when i tried executing same 30+ queries using my command line why is it so
why should we reestablish the connection

This didn't work

```
 import MySQLdb
 con = MySQLdb.connect(hostname,user, password, dbname, port)
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(query1)
 .
 .
 .
 cur.execute(query50)
 cur.execute('commit')
 cur.close()
 con.close()
```

This Worked

```
 import MySQLdb
 con = MySQLdb.connect(hostname,user, password, dbname, port)
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(query1)
 .
 .
 cur.execute(query10)
 cur.execute('commit')
 cur.close()
 con.close()

 #reestablished connection

 con = MySQLdb.connect(hostname,user, password, dbname, port)
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(query11)
 .
 .
 cur.execute(query20)
 cur.execute('commit')
 cur.close()
 con.close()

 #reestablished connection

 con = MySQLdb.connect(hostname,user, password, dbname, port)
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(query21)
 .
 .
 cur.execute(query30)
 cur.execute('commit')
 cur.close()
 con.close()
```

Comment: do you have a `commit` in the first block? have you tried 50 `select * from some_table` in the first block to see if that works?

Comment: yes there is a commit in first block also

Comment: How does query1 to query50 looks like?

Comment: what happens if you replace the 50 queries in the first block with the first 10 from the second block? Remove all other free variables and isolate the faulty as much as possible!

Comment: its insert of numbers from 1 to 50  one by one into table i  could  see 1-15 values in db but remaining are not updated in database . which means queries are executed partially

Comment: wierd... might be rate limiting within amazon rds or a firewall rate limiter.

Comment: will there be any such limit of maximum requests per connection